# How to invoke browser from my AWS linux EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I started a nodejs application on port 8000, on my aws ec2 instance. I was able to do wget and see the output code as well on the screen.

---

wget http://localhost:8000
--2018-10-22 13:40:17--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 366 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                              100%[============================================================================>]     366  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2018-10-22 13:40:17 (73.9 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [366/366]

---

I opened port no. 8000 on my EC2 instance using a security group setting for inbound and outbound. Still I can access using http://ipaddress:8000 . Any other suggestions to see my application on the browser please

[Security Group Settings](http://www.screencast.com/t/7r3pUe4VO)

Comment: Is your web server listening on all ports (0.0.0.0) or just localhost?

Comment: When you're trying to use http://ipaddress:8000, which IP address are you using? And which instance are you calling it from? If you're calling from outside your AWS VPC, you'll likely have to use a public IP rather than internal

Comment: Hi Quasar, I am using on all ports (0.0.0.0) as shown in this screenshot http://www.screencast.com/t/0ouiMt9S9

Comment: hI Sofcal, I am using the IP address provided by amazon..as shown in the screenshot: http://www.screencast.com/t/3yah8pLGhGOU

Comment: Even I tried the public IP also: Please see this screenshot: http://www.screencast.com/t/CbZzM51l

Answer (score 0):

I am able to browse my website (Nodejs) from port 3000 now on AWS. But strangly my problem with port 8000 still remains same. I can see the curl http://localhost:8000 but when I go to the browser using the same public IP , it is saying  refused to connect.
{ Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED} Not sure what is the problem with port 8000. I have enabled the port 8000 and also port 443 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the bind IP address from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` and try.

By specifying 0.0.0.0, the server will bind to all IPs, allowing both "localhost" to continue to work (locally) as well as allowing the server to be accessed from external devices via the machine's IP or hostname.